# PHP Check Empty Value From Separate File

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, error-handling

I have a registration page and I am going to check the values of each field in both javascript and PHP. The problem is I have the registration code behind in a separate file. I put it in a seperate file because I am querying a database and much more so I ruled out posting to self. I then figured that redirecting to an separate error page would be overkill.

So what I would like to do is redirect to the registration page with the error message at the top or something of the sort just like if I was posting the form to self. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to have registration code in the separate file.
However, this file have to be the registration page itself.
While the form is stored in the another file and just get included.

Here is the sketch of the registration code

```
<?  
include 'config.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    // if no errors - saving data 
    // and then redirect:
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```

and a *template* contains the form and the error mesages

```
<? if ($err): ?>
  <? foreach($err as $e): ?>
<div class="err"><?=$e?></div>
  <? endforeach ?>
<? endif ?>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$form['name']?>">
  <textarea name="comments"><?=$form['comments']?></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is the most common way of form processing called [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: isn't including things with database information a bad practice? Because I mean at some point I am going to have to submit all this to a database and that is where the separate file comes in.

Comment: what? "including things with database information a bad practice"? What do you mean? What information and why it is bad practice?

Comment: @Howdy If I got you correctly, it's database credentials and connect? It is ALWAYS stored in a separate file and gets included into every script required a database connection. I just added such an include to my code.

Comment: Oh ok, so what's the difference between including the credentials vs having them in the same file? I mean from my understanding an include is just a more organized way to add more code without making the actual code page longer.

Comment: @Howdy sure, it is. That's why I wondered if "including things with database information a bad practice". Though "more organized" means not to make the page shorter but to avoid repetitions. Having db pass in a single file you can change it in a moment - that's the profit.

Comment: so really not dangerous per se just more organized?

Comment: @Howdy I don't know where did you get that idea, but yes - nothing dangerous. include is a cornerstone of the whole PHP application, one of most useful things. Although every tool can be dangerous of improper use but nothing dangerous in the include per se.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just post to self? All you must do is structure the php so that once verified it inserts the data ect...

```
 if( isset($_POST[ 'submit' ]) ){
 //Do checks
 // if all checks pass do your thing.
 //      redirect.... header();
 exit;
 }
 // you could then do if( isset($_POST['name']) ){ echo 'name'; } to repopulate the fields so you don't irritate the user.
```

If you still insist on doing it this way still use header() to redirect your user. (not a plesent user experience in my opinion...and the user have to refill all the data out again.)

Comment: Is it not bad practice to have database query / database information in the same file as your html/forms?

Answer (score -1):

You could post to your authentication page, check if they have a blank field or whatever, then redirect via

```
header(Location:<your url here>?error=1);
```

back to the original page and have that page check for the GET variable `$_GET['error']`. If that variable is 1, display some error.

Is this what you are looking for?